# Mailman installation username and password?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mailing-lists, mailman

First, I've installed lasted version of Iredmail on Ubuntu 14.04 then installed mailman. After installation, I have opened mailman URL but It prompted me a dialogue to enter username and password

I've tried email and password of mailman aliases, system username and password, admin's iredmail email and password but still cannot log in.

anyone knows how to solve this?

Now, I know that is about Authentication cookie. It might not work but i still have no idea about username and password

I still cannot solve my problem but i have a tip for person who meet a problem like me

Tip: I used alias map and postfix to redirect messages. With alias map, we can create lists of email and then send messages to @. After got a message, postfix will redirect them to emails in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I had a very similar same problem. My problem (which may or may not be *exactly* the same to yours) was that I installed mailman and postorius (the UI for mailman that by default loads on localhost:8000) and I was trying to login to that. When I started from scratch and installed the [Mailman Bundler](https://mailman-bundler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), HyperKitty had installed as well and during *that* install is where I was prompted for login information. That login information was what I used to login at localhost:8000 (the UI for mailman).

For what it's worth I asked almost the exact same question and once I resolved it, I traced my steps and wrote them for others. You can find my post  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1004432/mailman3-ui-postorius-where-is-my-admin-login-info-getting-set).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I evaded the problem by configure  postfix as a mailing list, but I wil try again.