# mailman3 ui - 'postorius' where is my admin login info getting set?

Tags: mailman

After many trials and tribulations I have finally installed mailman3 and the Postorius UI for Ubuntu 14.04. I navigate to the 127.0.0.1:8000 just as directed, and the UI says "There are currently no mailing lists." which is correct. I don't have any set up.  I visit the "login" link on the top right of the page where it prompts me for a username and password. I don't remember making these in the installation.

So my question is: Where is my login info stored for Postorius? Is there a default value for the login I should be entering?

I have yet to install hyperkitty, that's next on my list.

Just a heads up, I'm very python illiterate.
Thanks in advance, Dominic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed the setup and would like to share an explanation to save people the time I expended digging around the web trying to install Mailman3.

I first tried to do the Mailmand Bundler install that was found  [here](https://mailman-bundler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Unfortunately, when I finished the install the first time I didn't have the Postorius UI as promised. So I then tried to install all of the components of mailman3 separately, which left me to my original question. I wiped everything and started from scratch and it worked. Here's how I got it all to work.

The most imperative aspect of this install is the two separate versions of python: 2.7 & 3.4. (You will need both installed for this). I had horrific troubles creating two virtualenv's and that was where 60% of my problems were. (Go easy on me, I'm python illiterate).

To create my 2.7 virutalenv (we'll refer to them as venv's), this is the command I used. It will create a folder named 'venv-2.7' that you will 'activate'. Once activated, this is responsible for installing the entire bundle *except* for the mailman core. (The bundler handles that 'exception' on it's own, so you dont have to worry about that).

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv-2.7
```

The 3.4 venv was trouble for me because of my version of ubuntu (or at least that is what I was told when reading around the web). I found a set of commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1/488530#488530) that helped me out tremendously. Creating my venv-3.4 went as so:

```
python3.4 -m venv --without-pip venv-3.4
source ./venv-3.4/bin/activate
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-3.4.4.tar.gz
tar -vzxf setuptools-3.4.4.tar.gz
cd setuptools-3.4.4
python setup.py install
cd ..
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.6.tar.gz
tar -vzxf pip-1.5.6.tar.gz
cd pip-1.5.6
python setup.py install
cd ..
deactivate
```

Your venvs should be set up now which is 90% of the battle.

Go ahead and grab the bundler.

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman-bundler.git
```

Activate your 2.7 venv.

```
source venv-2.7/bin/activate
```

The rest of the instructions can be followed  [here](https://mailman-bundler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). But I will copy and paste them from there for ease or incase the page moves in the future.

Stolen from the link I attached:
*In the bundler directory, open the mailman_web/development.py file, look for the SECRET_KEY parameter and set something random.*

Then continue on... (You'll get a bunch of warnings, thats fine. As long as there are no errors).

```
pip install zc.buildout
buildout
```

Install less (I had to install sass too, so I included it).

```
sudo apt-get install node-less
sudo su -c "gem install sass"
```

Initialize Django's database.

```
./bin/mailman-post-update
```

Create a user to login as (I think this is specifically where my original question is answered and I just never reached this point).

```
./bin/mailman-web-django-admin createsuperuser
```

Start mailman

```
./bin/mailman start
```

Start Django which is the total UI - Postorius and hyperkitty

```
./bin/mailman-web-django-admin runserver &
```

**Extra:** I received an error including something about *COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS* when I first loaded the UI. I dug into *mailman-bundler/mailman_web/development.py* and found

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Remember when I said I was missing sass and was getting an error? I installed it and included it in this list, now I have:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

All of this gave me a working mailman3. Hope it can help some of you out.

***EDIT:*** I also updated virtualenv. I found the package on python's website. (I don't have enough rep to post a 3rd link to the package). But I downloaded it as so:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-13.1.2.tar.gz#md5=b989598f068d64b32dead530eb25589a
```